# how to send an email with flask-mail from a bussiness acount?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, flask-mail

I`m trying to send mails with flask-mail, which I achieved since anaccount@gmail.com, but in production we need to send the mail from anaccount@myowndomain.mx which fails because from "@gmail.com" i can permit less secure apps, but in bussiness gmail acount I can´t...so my question is...
¿Is there another way to permite less secure apps? or ¿How coul I do my app more secure?, a workaround?
thanks in advance.

here´s my flask-mail configuration.

```
from flask_mail import Mail, Message 

app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = '@myowndomain.mx'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = '**********'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
mail = Mail(app)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem in base of this:
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/03/send-email-programmatically-with-gmail-python-and-flask.html

first you have to create a two step verification to your gmail account, then create an app password, and use this app pasword in the flask-mail configuration

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

1. Enable "Less secure app" button in respective google account
2. Enable 2 step verification in respective account(complete the
   steps which google prompts to setup 2 step verification)
3. Enable the App password which is present in security tab of
   respective google account
4. Select the device and app option
5. copy paste the 16 digit app password your mail
   configuration `(e.g., MAIL_PASSWORD=16digit/character app password)`